# Postmaster Expiration_Date In "Post Date Specific" Field

Tags: date, postmaster

I'm currently looking to send out an email using Postmaster when an entry expires. My entry will be assigned a expiration date, so im curious if I can use this variable in the "Post Date Specific" field. Currently the field states that you can put a dynamic date.

Will it work with the {parcel:expiration_date format="%d/%m/%Y-%g:%i:%s"}? If it does, its not working for me.. Maybe its my formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is definitely the formatting. I tested this locally and found that the format you used returns `FALSE` when it's passed to the `strtotime()` method. This because PHP cannot recognize the format to convert it to a timestamp, thus returning `FALSE` which will force the email to be sent immediately. Use the following format:

```
{parcel:expiration_date format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s"}
```

Comment: Suggestion: add the specific date format requirement to the docs.